# Google Cloud Storage permission error while setting file visibility during upload

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, lumen

I am trying to upload images to GCS using the [Laravel GCS wrapper](https://github.com/Superbalist/laravel-google-cloud-storage). I want that every image uploaded is visible to anyone. I've set my bucket permissions as read and write to anyone.

If I do like this, it works perfectly but images are not public:

```
Storage::disk('gcs')->put($location, $image);
```

However, if do like this, which should upload image and make it public, it throws error

> 403 Insufficient Permission

```
Storage::disk('gcs')->setVisibility($filename, 'public')->put($location, $image);
```

So the `->setVisibility()` is giving me the error.

Can anybody explain me why? Is it about code or is it the bucket permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "I've set my bucket permissions as read and write to anyone." I suspect you mean you have granted allUsers:WRITER/allUsers:READER on the legacy bucket ACL.

The legacy ACL API does not support granting object level permissions at the bucket level.  Thus allUsers:READER on the bucket only grants object list permission, it does not grant object get permissions.  Instead you needed to change the default_object_acl to grant permissions to new objects created in the bucket.

However, rather than using the legacy ACL API, you would likely rather use IAM to grant the permissions you want, as these permissions will be inherited by all objects in the bucket, rather than being set on individual objects on creation.

`gsutil iam ch allUsers:objectViewer gs://ex-bucket`

Comment: Did you remove the 'setVisibility' call?  It is no longer necessary.  You should just need to call 'Storage::disk('gcs')->put($location, $image);' and the file should be publicly readable.

Comment: Ohh my bad. So basically all uploaded images have now the read permission to anyone?